# SQL Unpivot the row and get Order Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a row with several diagnosis codes. How do I unpivot the columns into rows? I tried the below query to unpivot, but I'm not sure how to get the `DX_Order` which is the column number, eg, for `DX01`, `DX_Order`=1. I believe the NULLs are taken care by `UNPIVOT.`

**Current table**

```
+----+------+-------+-------+------+----+------+
| ID | Name | DX01  | DX02  | DX03 | .. | DX25 |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+----+------+
|  1 | John | 426S3 | G2634 | NULL | .. | NULL |
+----+------+-------+-------+------+----+------+
```

**Expected result**

```
+----+------+----------+-------+
| ID | Name | DX_Order |  DX   |
+----+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | John |        1 | 426S3 |
|  1 | John |        2 | G2634 |
+----+------+----------+-------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ID, Name, DX
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, Name, DX01, DX02, DX03...DX25
  FROM dbo.Table
) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
  DX FOR DXs IN (DX01, DX02, DX03....DX25)
) AS up;
```

Comment: If your data will always have dx in ascending order without gaps then a simple row_number() over partition in the data could work for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Cross Apply` instead of `unpivot`. Along with `DX0n` columns you can add the order column as well

```
SELECT ID, Name, DX_Order, DX
  FROM dbo.Table
  Cross apply (values (DX01,1),(DX02,2),(DX03,3),...(DX025,25)) cs (DX, DX_Order)
  Where DX is not null
```

When there are some `NULL` values in `DX0n` columns and still you want the `DX_Order` to be sequence then

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       DX_Order = Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY DX_Order),
       DX
FROM   (SELECT ID, NAME, DX_Order, DX
        FROM   dbo.Table
               CROSS apply (VALUES (DX01,1),(DX02,2),(DX03,3),..(DX025,25)) cs (DX, DX_Order)
        WHERE  DX IS NOT NULL) a
```

Answer (score 1):

Pரதீப் solution would be my first option (+1), and is certainly more performant.

However, the following will dynamically unpivot your data without having to specify all the fields and without actually using dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(50),DX01 varchar(50),DX02 varchar(50),DX03 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'John','426S3','G2634',null)


Select A.ID
      ,A.Name
      ,DX_Order= C.ColNr
      ,DX = C.Value
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select ColNr = row_number() over (order by (Select null))
                      ,Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','Name')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name    DX_Order    DX
1   John    1           426S3
1   John    2           G2634
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
SELECT ID,DX_Order,DX
       FROM dbo.TableN
                CROSS apply 
(VALUES ([DX01],1),([DX02],2)) cs (DX,DX_Order)
WHERE DX IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by executing dynamic SQL query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = stuff((
        select ' union all select [ID], [Name], cast(replace(' 
        + char(39) + [column_name] + char(39) + ', ' + char(39) 
        + 'DX' + char(39) + ',' + char(39) + char(39) + ') as int) as [DX_Order],
        case when [' + [column_name] + '] is not null then [' + [column_name] 
        + '] else null end as [DX] from [your_table_name]'
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'your_table_name'
        and [column_name] like 'DX%'
        order by ordinal_position
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 11, ''
);

select @sql = 'select t.* from (' + @sql + ') t where t.[DX] is not null;';

exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data creation

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.temp') iS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE temp
;With cte(ID , Name , DX01  , DX02  , DX03 , DX25 )
AS
( SELECT 1 , 'John' , '426S3' , 'G2634' , NULL,NULL 
)
SELECT * INTO temp FROM cte
```

Using Dynamic Sql , we can get the expected Result when we have n number of columns

```
DECLARE @SQlColumn nvarchar(max)
        ,@SQl nvarchar(max)


SELECT @SQlColumn= STUFF((SELECT ', '+Columnname  FROM
                (
            SELECT  '( '+ 'CAST('+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+' AS VARCHAR(30)),CAST(REPLACE('''+COLUMN_NAME+''+''','''+'DX'+''',''' +''''+') AS VARCHAR(30)))'  AS Columnname
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME='temp' AND COLUMN_NAME <>'Id' AND COLUMN_NAME <>'Name'
                )dt FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @SQl='  SELECT ID
                 ,Name
                 ,DX
                 ,DX_Order FROM temp 
            CROSS APPLY (VALUES '+ @SQlColumn + ') dt (DX,DX_Order) WHERE DX IS NOT NULL'
PRINT @SQl
EXEC(@SQl)
```

Result

```
  ID    Name    DX_Order    DX
  ------------------------------
   1    John    01         426S3
   1    John    02         G2634
```